# Hypergraph matching -> adjacency matrix?

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, discrete-optimization

I need to do a matching on a hypergraph. I read that in the case of a hypergraph there is no adjacency matrix.

How do I represent edges then?

Answer (score 2):

Edges are represented as sets of vertices. With classical graphs, an edge can be represented by the set containing its 2 endpoints. With hypergraphs, they are represented by a set containing more than 2 nodes e.g. $e_i = \lbrace v_1, v_2, ... , v_n \rbrace$.
Incidence matrices are straightforward, just look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). About incidence matrices you may be interested by [this](https://books.google.fr/books?id=DWZc9Ti_vBwC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=hypergraph+adjacency+matrix&source=bl&ots=2U-r4yz3W5&sig=8nJ5RZ2V8elXWFcPxby0X0msxk8&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvidfC3pjWAhWSaVAKHYUKCrIQ6AEIOzAC#v=onepage&q=hypergraph%20adjacency%20matrix&f=false)

Comment: The OP is asking about adjacency matrices, not incident matrices.